# Is the posix namespace used?

Tags: c++, c++11, posix, language-lawyer

The C++11 standard [§17.6.4.2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.posix) defines `posix` as a reserved namespace for use by ISO/IEC 9945 and other POSIX standards, and states that C++ programs adding declarations or definitions to the `posix` namespace have undefined behaviour.

**Is that namespace actually used by ISO/IEC 9945 or any other POSIX standards?** If yes, please provide a reference.

### Notes:

- [N2667](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2667.htm) was voted in in [June, 2008](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2697.html).

Comment: "The POSIX liasion report to the LWG at the Bellevue meeting requested the reservation of possible namespaces **for future standardization work**. Two namespaces were mentioned as candidates: std::posix and ::posix." from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2667).

Comment: As far as I can tell, POSIX only mentions C++ in a few places: talking about how thread cancellation might interact with exceptions and how POSIX's "type-generic" terminology for `tgmath.h` isn't really the same thing as C++ overloading. So I think that any standardization of `namespace posix` is in the future (if it ever occurs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

At time of writing, this is still a purely reserved namespace, not actually in use by anyone.

Recall that the vast majority of POSIX, if not all of POSIX, is entirely C++-unaware.